# Find all integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $x^4-12x²+x^2y^2+30 < 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Find all integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $$x^4-12x²+x^2y^2+30 < 0$$

Letting $a = x^2$ and $b = y^2$ I got $$a^2-12a+ab+30 < 0$$

from which I managed to get $$a^2-12+30+ab <0 \Rightarrow (a-6)^2+ab < 6.$$

However I'm not sure how to proceed from here. What should I do?

Comment: $x^2(x^2-12)+x^2y^2+30<0$ so you definitely want $x^2-12<0$ and you want $x^2(x^2-12)<-30$

Answer (score 1):

You have $(a-6)^2< 6$, $a\ge 0$. So $(a-6)^2\in \{0,1,4\}$. If $(a-6)^2=0$, then $a=6$, impossible since $a=x^2$.

$(a-6)^2=1$ implies $a-6=\pm 1$, $a=5 $ or $a=7$, impossible again.

Finally $(a-6)^2=4$ imples $a=6\pm 2$, the only possibility is $a=4$. But then $(a-6)^2+ab<6$ means $ab<2$, so $b=0$.

Conclusion: $x=\pm 2, y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $x\ne0$,

$$\dfrac{x^4-12x^2+30}{x^2}<-y^2$$

$$\iff x^2+\dfrac{30}{x^2}<12-y^2\le12$$

Now  $x^2+\dfrac{30}{x^2}<12\iff0>x^4-12x^2+30=(x^2-6)^2-6$

$(x^2-6)^2<6\iff-\sqrt6<x^2-6<\sqrt6\iff6-\sqrt6<x^2<6+\sqrt6$

But $6+\sqrt6<9$ and $6-\sqrt6>3\implies 3<x^2<9$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2y^2<6-(x^2-6)^2\leq6-2^2=2,$$ which says $$x^2y^2=0$$ or $$x^2y^2=1.$$
The last is impossible because $x^2=4.$

Can you end it now?